# Multiple Audio Trim with multiple channels of audio ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, trim, concatenation

I am looking for a way to trim a single video with 4 channels of audio in multiple places and then concat the pieces together maintaining the 4 audio channel trims as well.

I have the following ffmpeg script that works but only takes the 1st channel of audio

Path\ffmpeg -i Path\ONEONONE_0052_NETW_4X3FF_30FPS_A3_SD_CC.mov  -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=95.0173:246.845,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [0:a]atrim=95.0173:246.845,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; [0:v]trim=249.043:729.071,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [0:a]atrim=249.043:729.071,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; [0:v]trim=731.199:1271.27,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; [0:a=]atrim=731.199:1271.27,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; [0:v]trim=1273.46:1324.01,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; [0:a]atrim=1273.46:1324.01,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; [0:v]trim=1326.1:1351.61,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4]; [0:a]atrim=1326.1:1351.61,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a4]; [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3][v4][a4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [outv][outa]" -ac 4 -map [outv] -map [outa]  -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -s 720x486  -c:a pcm_s24le  Path\ONE_ON_ONE_0052_NETW_4X3FF_30FPS_A3_SD_CC_CUTNEW.mov

Any suggestions?

Comment: Copy and paste the complete log from your command.